unwanted differences white spacing around tripcolor in Matplotlib, compared to pcolormesh
I've been working on visualizing some 2D heightmap data using matplotlib and came across a notable difference in the output when using pcolormesh vs. tripcolor. To illustrate, I've created side-by-side plots using the same dataset with both functions. I need to get rid of the white space in tripcolor (the size of pcolormesh is what I need).
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import os
from os.path import realpath, dirname

# Define the output directory
output_dir = realpath(dirname(__file__))

# Create sample data for demonstration
resolution = 100
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, resolution)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, resolution)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = np.sin(np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2))

# Flatten the grid and data for tripcolor
x_flat = x.flatten()
y_flat = y.flatten()
z_flat = z.flatten()

# Create the LinearSegmentedColormap
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap', ['white', 'black'])

# Create the figure with two subplots
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(16, 8))

# pcolormesh plot
c1 = ax1.pcolormesh(x, y, z, cmap=cmap, shading='gouraud')
ax1.set_title('pcolormesh')
ax1.axis('off')  # Turn off the axis

# tripcolor plot
c2 = ax2.tripcolor(x_flat, y_flat, z_flat, shading='gouraud', cmap=cmap)
ax2.set_title('tripcolor')
ax2.axis('off')  # Turn off the axis

comparison_path = os.path.join(output_dir, 'pcolormesh_vs_tripcolor.png')
plt.savefig(comparison_path, format='png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
plt.show()


I search high and low, but cannot seems to find out why and how to fix it. I tried with our without bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0.

pcolormesh seems to automatically set margins to 0, while tripcolor doesn't. With ax2.margins(x=0, y=0) you can remove these margins.

In fact the margins are just ignored for certain methods: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axes_margins.html#on-the-stickiness-of-certain-plotting-methods
